# Linux/Python: How can I hide sensitive information in a Python file, so that developers on the environment won't be able to access it?

Tags: python, mysql, linux, django, passwords

I've got a Django project running on an Ubuntu server. There are other developers who have the ability to ssh into the box and look at files. I want to make it so that the mysql credentials and api keys in `settings.py` are maybe separated into a different file that's only viewable by the root user, but also usable by the django project to run.

My previous approach was to make the passwords file only accesible to root:root with `chmod 600`, but my `settings.py` throws an `ImportError` when it tries to import the password file's variables. I read about setuid, but that doesn't seem very secure at all. What's a good approach for what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: Why do people have access to your machine if you don't trust them? Especially if they are developers, which usually implies write access to the codebase, they could always add code revealing your credentials to them. If they just need read access on the other hand, why do they have access to your server at all? Just use a private git repo and let them use that to access your code.

Comment: We trust them to some degree, but some parts of the code should not be touched at all, and we need to be sure of that. This is for just in case they accidentally write over something important. Or maybe they're feeling sinister. So with this kind of constraint... I'm hoping there's some kind of solution :/

Comment: "We trust them to some degree, but some parts of the code should not be touched at all, and we need to be sure of that." - Sounds like a perfect application for centralized version control. Keep the file on the server, extract and run as needed.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Yep, we've got svn tracking everything, but we still want to have this layer of security.

Comment: @pyramidface, I think you need to read up on the security. Because effectively you ask for a possibility to give people a script (== text file) to run, but the script they may not modify. Outside the code obfuscation (or coversion to compiled language and distribution of a binary), that's just impossible: if you can run it, you can read; if you can read, you can make a copy; if you can make a copy, you can modify the copy, and run the modified copy.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Ah I didn't know that. Is there some resource I could read up on that? How could they see they read the contents of the file if they can only execute it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at filesystem ACLs, [setfacl manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html).

You can have the files in questioned owned and readable only by the root user, but also allow whatever user the Django code is running as (your user name, apache user, etc) to have read access.  Filesystem ACLs allow much more granular access control than standard owner/group/other file permissions

Answer (score 1):

I'd place the password file in a directory with 600 permissions owned by the Django user.  The Django user would be able to do what it needed to and nobody else would even be able to look in the directory (except root and Django)

Another thing you could do would be to store it in a database and set it so that the root user and the Django user in the DB have unique passwords, that way only the person with those passwords could access it.  IE system root is no longer the same as DB root.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what [dj-database-url](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dj-database-url) was created for!

Using this package you can store DB information in your user's environment variable. anyone who login from different account won't have access to db details

How to use?

Configure your database in settings.py from `DATABASE_URL` (default is optional):

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://...')}
```

Then in your shell

```
$ export DATABASE_URL="postgress://user:password@host/databasename"
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

This will run the server with the connection you specified, if `DATABASE_URL` is not defined then assume the connection passed by the optional `default` parameter.

ideally you would put

```
 export DATABASE_URL="postgress://user:password@host/databasename"
```

inside your .bashrc file inside your home directory so that only you can read it

Comment: That seems like it's storing the database credentials in plaintext in settings.py. I'm trying to move anything credential related to another file that's locked down so that only root can django and view it, and have settings.py import it.

Comment: No, the goal of the plugin is **avoid** storing database credentials in the settings.py file. I've updated my answer to add some explaination

Answer (score -2):

This is discussed in the [SplitSettings page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings) on `code.djangoproject.com`. They have several suggestions such as

```
SECRET_KEY = open(os.path.expanduser('~/.gallery-secret')).read().strip()
```

where `.gallery-secret` is limited to read by django user only (root still gets its way, of course). I prefer an environment variable such as `MYAPP_OPTIONS=/etc/opt/myapp/` used with `os.path.expandvar` so that the user account doesn't need a home directory and so that developers can point to test credentials easily.